DECODER routines::unsupported when using SHA256WithRSA to generate a signature with secret key and string data in node
The node.js app (typescript) needs to send a signature to the web service, the process requires

based on the algorithm SHA256WithRSA
use client's secret key to sign the client's data and output the signature
encode the signature into based64

I tried the code
   import { createHmac } from 'crypto';
   const signature = createHmac('sha256', config.secret).update(data).digest('hex');
   const signature1 = Buffer.from(signature, 'hex').toString('base64')

but it seems HMAC is not SHA256WithRSA, so I tried the code
   import { createSign  } from 'crypto';
    const sign = createSign('RSA-SHA256');
    sign.update(data);
    const signature = sign.sign(config.secret, 'base64');

however the program throws out an error
    Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
at Object.signOneShot (node:internal/crypto/sig:163:15)

on 'signature = sign.sign(config.secret, 'base64')'
how would I implement this task?
about the secret key, it is generated in a tool with RSA2 algorithm, the secret key is said to be RSA 2048, as shown below
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCcZdmCvpg8tiiKMGs1GkYqNPZtW....

I even tried to add the pem tag like
const pemKey = `
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    ${secretkey}
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    `;

and use the pemKey as the secretkey but still outputs the same error.
Additionally, i tried to use another library
import * as crypto from 'node:crypto'
    const signature =  crypto.sign(
      "sha256",
      Buffer.from(encodedParams),
      {
          key: privateKey,
          padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING,
      }
  ).toString('base64')

but still with the same error.
I tried the method in ubuntu 22.04 (node 18.20) and mac 11.7.10, (node 20.11).
Since crypto is depending on openssl, I found the openssl version in both system is 1.11 which is too old for node.js , so I upgraded the openssl lib to version 3. But still does't solve my problem, the same error again and again.

Perhaps config.secret is not what is expected. Can you provide more information about config.secret, included how it was created and it's format. Step #2 should say "use client's private key ..."

That's right HMAC is not SHA256WithRSA. For signing with RSA you need a private RSA key. Probably config.secret is not such a key! The required key may be a private RSA key in PKCS#1 or PKCS#8 format (PEM or DER encoded) or a JWK, s. sign.sign().

I have tried multiple ways, like node:crypto library, upgrade the openssl to 3.0, and tried the secret key as well, all seem to fail

With a valid key, the code works, s. online https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/12yx. There may be something wrong with your key. Check the key (openssl rsa -in your.key -check), describe the key generation tool or post a non-productive key generated with that tool.

@Topaco thanks，you just help me I think it is the problem of the key.
